# Indicate class type on deserialization of JSON string to Object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to de-serialize a JSON string into an object in Python, while indicating the specific class type for each object.
Here is an example JSON:

```
{
    "Vehicle":
    [
        {
            "$type": "Car",
            "Make": 1982,
            "Settings":
            {
                "$type": "CarSettings",
                "ESP": true
            }
        },
        {
            "$type": "Motorcycle",
            "Make": 2010,
            "Settings":
            {
                "$type": "MotorcycleSettings",
                "ABS": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that my classes are built this way:

- Vehicle
- Car : Vehicle
- Motorcycle : Vehicle

and:

- Settings
- CarSettings : Settings
- MotorcycleSettings : Settings

I figured it out for a **single type** representing the entire JSON using "json.loads" with "object_hook" but I can't seem to make it work for sub-classes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `object_hook` you define will get the dictionaries from the JSON string. Take this example:

```
def hook(dic):
  print(dic)
  return dic
```

Using it as a hook, with your example will produce:

```
{'$type': 'CarSettings', 'ESP': True}
{'$type': 'Car', 'Make': 1982, 'Settings': {'$type': 'CarSettings', 'ESP': True}}
{'$type': 'MotorcycleSettings', 'ABS': True}
{'$type': 'Motorcycle', 'Make': 2010, 'Settings': {'$type': 'MotorcycleSettings', 'ABS': True}}
```

Therefore in the `hook()` function you take the *$type* element and act according to that.

```
def hook(dic):
  if dic['$type'] == "Car":
     return Car(**dic) # assuming Car constructor can take kwargs
  if dic['$type'] == "Motorcycle":
     return Motorcycle(**dic) # assuming Motorcycle constructor can take kwargs
```

The `hook()` will be called on the most nested dictionary first. So if you parse the *CarSettings* and return that object from the `hook()` than the dictionary for the Car (`'$type': 'Car'`) will already contain the `CarSettings` type object.

```
{'$type': 'Car', 'Make': 1982, 'Settings': <__main__.CarSettings object at 0x000001FF4FD6A550>}
```

If you have many classes, make a dictionary ordering a type for a typename, and use that for object creation.

```
types = {
  'Car' : Car,
  'Motorcycle' : Motorcycle,
}

def hook(dic):
  try:
     return types[dic['$type']](**dic)
  except KeyError:
     pass
```

Comment: You could also create a dictionary that maps from type names to classes, e.g. `typemap = {"Car": Car, "Motorcycle": Motorcycle, ...}` and then do `return typemap[dic['$type']](**dic)` instead of a bunch of `if` statements.